# How to secure .ASPXAUTH token

Tags: security, .net

How do you secure the .ASPXAUTH token so that it is sent over SSL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Directly from [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998310.aspx#paght000012_step3):

> To prevent forms authentication cookies from being captured and
>   tampered with while crossing the network, ensure that you use SSL with
>   all pages that require authenticated access and restrict forms
>   authentication tickets to SSL channels by setting `requireSSL="true"` on
>   the `<forms>` element.
>
> To restrict forms authentication cookies to SSL channels set `requireSSL="true"` on the `<forms>` element, as shown in the following code:
>
> `<forms loginUrl="Secure\Login.aspx" requireSSL="true" ... />`
>
> By setting `requireSSL="true"`, you set the secure cookie property that determines whether browsers should send the cookie back to the
>   server. With the secure property set, the cookie is sent by the
>   browser only to a secure page that is requested using an HTTPS URL.

**Note:** that when using `requireSSL="true"`, the auth cookie is only sent for pages requested via SSL.  So if you hit a page via HTTP (non-SSL), it may appear that you are not logged in.  This article talks about the issue and proposes a solution as it would pertain to a SharePoint site (but the theory is transferable): [Securing the authentication cookie for mixed SSL SharePoint sites](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2010/04/partial-ssl-sharepoint-sites-securing-the-authentication-cookie/)