# Secure Flag for ASPXAUTH Cookie

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

We have an externally facing application which was penetration-tested by an external security company. Application has been developed on ASP.NET MVC4 and running on IIS8/Windows 2012 Server.

One of the vulnerabilities reported was ASPXAUTH is not secure. When I checked on the cookie inspector, there are some cookies with Secure flag. But ASPXAUTH was not one of them.

I did  a bit of research, and  set these flags below on the web.config

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"  requireSSL=""  name="AppName" />
```

and

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

Despite these settings, the authentication cookie is not marked as secure. I assumed that thse flags should be enough to mark application cookies as secure, but there are a few other cookies which are also not marked as secure. I am not too concerned about them as they don't contain any sensitive information.  But I would like to flag ASPXAUTH  as secure.

My questions are,

1. With these flags set on the web.config, is having ASPXAUTH without secure flag a security issue?
2. If so, could you tell me what the correct way is to mark it as secure.

thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found this piece of code to which made my authentication cookie secure. I cant remember the source of this but if you add it to your global.asax, it sorts the issue. I do not know why but requireSSL=true in your  tag was not enough to make it secure.

```
  protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string authCookie = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

        foreach (string sCookie in Request.Cookies)
        {
            if (sCookie.Equals(authCookie))
            {
                // Set the cookie to be secure. Browsers will send the cookie
                // only to pages requested with https
                var httpCookie = Response.Cookies[sCookie];
                if (httpCookie != null) httpCookie.Secure = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AnarchistGreek, didn't work against IBM's AppScan. It still claims the cookie isn't secure.

Comment: I see, your code needs to be edited. The foreach statement should be accessing Request.Cookies instead of Response.Cookies.

Answer (score 12):

Your issue looks to be that because your form is incorrectly configured. You have:

```
<forms ... requireSSL="" ... />
```

and you should have

```
<forms ... requireSSL="true" ... />
```

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228262(v=vs.100).aspx) the `requireSSL` attribute in the `httpCookies` tag is overridden by the `requireSSL` attribute of the `forms` tag. You didn't set the value, but you specified it may cause IIS to use the default of `false`. You should set it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your secong question

Possible duplicate of [How to secure .ASPXAUTH token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981061/how-to-secure-aspxauth-token)

as per answer by [xelco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573083/xelco52)

> To prevent forms authentication cookies from being captured and
> tampered with while crossing the network, ensure that you use SSL with
> all pages that require authenticated access and restrict forms
> authentication tickets to SSL channels by setting `requireSSL="true"` on
> the `<forms>` element.
> To restrict forms authentication cookies to SSL channels set
> `requireSSL="true"` on the `<forms>` element, as shown in the following
> code:
>
> ```
> <forms loginUrl="Secure\Login.aspx" requireSSL="true" ... />
> ```
>
> By setting `requireSSL="true"`, you set the secure cookie property that
> determines whether browsers should send the cookie back to the server.
> With the secure property set, the cookie is sent by the browser only
> to a secure page that is requested using an HTTPS URL.

Comment: Thanks. I have read that answer and that is what I did as I stated in the question. I did exactly what is described, but ASPXAUTH token cookie is not still marked as secure.

Comment: I hate to repeat the obvious, but requireSSL is how you set the secure cookie flag.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag.

One thing to check is the hierarchy of the config files.  It may be set at the top web.config, but overwritten in the sub-directory.  You can also check in code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

An alteration to AnarchistGeek's answer: you don't want to iterate over Request.Cookies directly because adding a cookie by using the response collection makes the cookie immediately available in the request collection (see the note in the HttpRequest.Cookies docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.cookies?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequest_Cookies)). That will leave you with a "Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated" error when you go to set/alter the response .ASPXAUTH cookie, because it is also modifying the request collection.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string authCookie = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    string[] cookieNames = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

    foreach (string sCookie in cookieNames)
    {
        if (sCookie.Equals(authCookie))
        {
            var httpCookie = Response.Cookies[sCookie];
            if (httpCookie != null) httpCookie.Secure = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this particular solution will clear the existing value of the .ASPXAUTH cookie (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207878/cookie-loses-value-in-asp-net))